# MongoDB - Query not working in 2.6

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently migrating our database from Mongo 2.4.9 to 2.6.4.

I have an odd situation where a query that is giving good results in 2.4 is returning no documents in 2.6.

The query in question:

```
var dbSearch = {
    created: { $gte: new Date(1409815194808) },
    geolocation: {
        $geoWithin: {
            $center: [ [ 4.895167900000001, 52.3702157 ], 0.1125 ]
        }
    }
};
```

on that collection are the following (relevant) indexes:

```
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "created" : -1 }, "name" : "createdIndex", "ns" : "prod.search", "background" : true }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "geolocation" : "2d", "created" : -1 }, "name" : "geolocationCreatedIndex", "ns" : "prod.search" }
```

Running this query against Mongo 2.6 gives the following query-log:

```
{ created: { $gte: new Date(1409815194808) }, geolocation: { $geoWithin: { $center: [ [ 4.895167900000001, 52.3702157 ], 0.1125 ] } } } 
planSummary: IXSCAN { created: -1 } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:8196 nreturned:0 reslen:20 8ms
```

I'm firing this query to the database with NodeJS using the node-mongodb-native module.

Note that when i remove either one of the search fields (`created` or `geolocation`) the queries will produce the right results on 2.4 and 2.6. The combination (as posted above) gives no results on 2.6

**Edits with extra requested information**

Explain on mongo 2.4 query:

```
> db.search.find({created: { $gte: new Date(1409815194808) }, geolocation: {$geoWithin: {$center: [ [ 4.895167900000001, 52.3702157 ], 0.1125 ] } } }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "GeoBrowse-circle",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 321,
    "nscannedObjects" : 321,
    "nscanned" : 321,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 321,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 321,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 69,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "geolocation" : [ ]
    },
    "lookedAt" : NumberLong(8940),
    "matchesPerfd" : NumberLong(8538),
    "objectsLoaded" : NumberLong(8538),
    "pointsLoaded" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsSavedForYield" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsChangedOnYield" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsRemovedOnYield" : NumberLong(0),
    "server" : "ubmongo24.local:27017"
}
```

Explain on mongo 2.6 query:

```
> db.search.find({created: { $gte: new Date(1409815194808) }, geolocation: {$geoWithin: {$center: [ [ 4.895167900000001, 52.3702157 ], 0.1125 ] } } }).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor createdIndex",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1403,
    "nscanned" : 1403,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2808,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2808,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 21,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 8,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "created" : [
            [
                ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ"),
                ISODate("2014-09-04T07:19:54.808Z")
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "ubmongo26.local:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: Do you have the latest node mongo driver?

Comment: Can you do an explain on 2.4 and 2.6 and add the results to the question - FYI, there is an open issue on compound geo indexes in 2.6: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14264 but not quite the same as your reported results

Comment: @AdamComerford I added the explain information to the post. The item you referred to looks it might be related.

Comment: @joao yes, i used node-mongodb-native 1.4.12, which should be the latest according to github

Answer (score 1):

Based on the explain output, the issue appears to be the index being chosen by the query optimizer (which was extensively overhauled in 2.6 - mostly for the better, but it does meant there are new edge cases).  It is using the single field `createdIndex` rather than the compound index being used in 2.4

Try hinting the `geolocationCreatedIndex` index in 2.6 (`.hint({ "geolocation" : "2d", "created" : -1 })`) and see if that fixes your issues - it is choosing the `createdIndex` instead by default and hence not using the geo index at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using the $hint gives me the proper results on this case.

However this makes me a bit hesitant to move to to Mongo 2.6 at this point since i feel that 'selecting the proper index to use' is a very important db-feature and i'm reluctant to trust it at this point.

Can you give an advice on the way forward from here:
- Should i report this as a Bug to MongoDB?
- Would i really need to check all my queries for proper index use?
- Are there index 'best practices' that i can use to increase the chance that 2.6 would select the proper indexes?

Thanks

Comment: That's tough to say for sure, might need a kernel engineer to weigh in, so a Jira issue would mean they take a look. To explain, I think that the optimizer may be doing the "right" thing - technically $geowithin does not require a geo index, and I am betting that the created index returns the initial 101 docs first and is hence chosen by the optimizer.  Hinting or using a filter (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#index-filters) will workaround it in the interim, but it may be worth tweaking the optimizer for this type of query in general